# BookSleeve BlockingRemoveLeft is only returning some of the items pushed into the list

Tags: c#, redis, booksleeve

I'm trying to put together a *super* simple queuing sample based on BookSleeve.

Here's what I have so far for the queue consumer side:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using BookSleeve;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var redis = new RedisConnection("127.0.0.1"))
        {
            redis.Open();
            while (true)
            {
                // BRPOP the queue
                var t = redis.Lists.BlockingRemoveFirst(0, new[] { "test" }, 0);
                t.Wait();
                var val = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(t.Result.Item2);
                Console.WriteLine("Got: {0}", val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running the following in [LINQPad](http://www.linkpad.net) as the producer:

```
using(var redis = new RedisConnection("localhost")) 
{
    redis.Open();
    foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)) 
    {
        // LPUSH
        redis.Lists.AddFirst(0, "test", "foo" + i)
            // Call wait to keep things in order
            .Wait();
    }   

    Thread.Sleep(500); // Let Redis do it's thing
    Console.WriteLine("queue length: " + redis.Lists.GetLength(0, "test").Result);
}
```

I'm getting some really weird results though:

1st run:

```
Got: foo2
Got: foo5
Got: foo7
Got: foo9
```

2nd run:

```
Got: foo1
Got: foo4
Got: foo7
```

3rd run:

```
Got: foo0
Got: foo3
Got: foo6
Got: foo8
```

Also, after every run, LINQPad outputs: `queue length: 0`, and running `LLEN test` using the actual redis client returns `(integer) 0`.

I can't help but feel that I'm missing something here, most likely having to do with the async stuff, but I just can't see it.

My redis version is 2.8.3, BookSleeve version is 1.3.41.

The actual question here is: **Why is BookSleeve only returning a subset of the messages that are sent to the redis list?**

Comment: Will look this evening. As a side note: I would usually say "avoid blocking calls (prefer pub/sub notification)" - it hurts multiplexers something crazy. However, it should work. More later.

Comment: Random thought: there's no chance you have a second copy of the consumer exe running somewhere taking some of the items?

Comment: One of the first things I checked, actually. It was the only process connected to redis at the time.

Comment: k - busy with family stuff at the moment, but will look later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply can't get it to error. Are you **absolutey sure** you only have 1 consumer? Note that the reason the **order** is unpredictable is because you are using it as a stack rather than a queue - to get reliable order you should either add to the start and remove from the end, or add to the end and remove from the start. If you add and remove from the start it is random-ish order.

However, it works fine for me. Console output:

```
Got: foo0
Got: foo1
Got: foo3
Got: foo5
Got: foo6
Got: foo8
Got: foo9
Got: foo7
Got: foo4
Got: foo2
queue length: 0
```

I suggest using `redis-cli` in `monitor` mode - for me, I get the following output:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> monitor
OK
1389454168.068869 [0 127.0.0.1:4957] "INFO"
1389454168.068869 [0 127.0.0.1:4957] "CONFIG" "GET" "timeout"
1389454168.068869 [0 127.0.0.1:4957] "DEL" "test"
1389454168.129869 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "INFO"
1389454168.129869 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "CONFIG" "GET" "timeout"
1389454168.136869 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.139872 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "INFO"
1389454168.139872 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "CONFIG" "GET" "timeout"
1389454168.139872 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LPUSH" "test" "foo0"
1389454168.142869 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LPUSH" "test" "foo1"
1389454168.142869 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.142869 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LPUSH" "test" "foo2"
1389454168.143871 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LPUSH" "test" "foo3"
1389454168.143871 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.143871 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LPUSH" "test" "foo4"
1389454168.143871 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LPUSH" "test" "foo5"
1389454168.144870 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.144870 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LPUSH" "test" "foo6"
1389454168.144870 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.144870 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LPUSH" "test" "foo7"
1389454168.145869 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LPUSH" "test" "foo8"
1389454168.145869 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.145869 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LPUSH" "test" "foo9"
1389454168.145869 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.146869 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.146869 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.147870 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.147870 [0 127.0.0.1:4958] "BLPOP" "test" "0"
1389454168.648594 [0 127.0.0.1:4959] "LLEN" "test"
```

Here connection 4957 is one that just removes the key (to ensure a known state); 4958 is the consumer, and 4959 is the producer.

For reference, I'm using the [2.6.12 Windows build](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Redis-64/) in the above test (because I'm on my Windows laptop, and didn't have time to set up a linux VM) - but: I would expect the same on the official linux builds too.

So again: are you *sure* (via `redis-cli`) that you only have 2 connections involved here?

If I change to `AddLast`:

```
Got: foo0
Got: foo1
Got: foo2
Got: foo3
Got: foo4
Got: foo5
Got: foo6
Got: foo7
Got: foo8
Got: foo9
queue length: 0
```

Comment: Additional thought: you can also use `client list` to see the current connections along with their last commmand, their current state, etc. In particular, the `flags` property includes a `b` if it is a blocking operation.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. The thing that stumped me is I got this behavior immediately after restarting redis (which I have running in a Linux VM).

Comment: Interesting though: why is your output non-sequential? I would think that the code I posted should produce FIFO behavior

Comment: @ross I explained that in my answer and (see the end) showed how to fix it. Basically, no you didn't write FIFO

Comment: I found out what was going on (it did have to do with orphaned connections), gonna write a blog post about it.

Comment: Okay, finally got a chance to put it up: http://rossipedia.com/blog/2014/01/redis-i-like-you-but-youre-crazy/